# Android - Intercept sharing intent from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to know if it's possible for my app to be notified when the user presses the share button, even if then selects another app on the list.

Something like a BroadcastReceiver for this event (Intent ACTION_SEND), but maybe it isn't possible, or simply a Service running all the time, checking some condition.

Could it be possible to achieve what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Share button in your application or others?

Comment: Share button in others

Answer (score 0):

You can not Intercept other applications Sharing Intent, but there's a possibility to intercept if you want to intercept your own applications'. http://xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article12/intent-intercept